# cURL socks5 proxy: "Empty reply from server"

Tags: proxy, curl, socks

I'm accessing an http resource using Chrome, FoxyProxy without any problems. The proxy is defined as `socks5` in the standard port `1080`.

I've tried accessing the same resource using cURL (actual URLs changed for privacy reasons):

```
$ curl -vvv -socks5 SOCKS_SERVER:1080 -X GET "THE_URL_FROM_BROWSER"
```

And got:

```
* About to connect() to SOCKS_SERVER port 1080 (#0)
*   Trying IP... connected
* Connected to SOCKS_SERVER (IP) port 1080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: SOCKS_SERVER:1080
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host SOCKS_SERVER left intact
* Connection #0 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection #0
* About to connect() to URL_HOST port 80 (#0)
*   Trying SOME_IP...
```

Which never comes back with a response.

Any idea why cURL can't access the same resource accessed by FoxyProxy?

Answer (score 5):

I get the same result, and looking at the strace output, it tries to connect to URL_HOST directly.

However if I use

```
curl -x socks5://SOCKS_SERVER:1080 "THE_URL_FROM_BROWSER"
```

It does work as expected (use socks4a or socks5h to have hostnames resolved by the proxy, if supported)